# How to induce blinks on JTextField labels continously?

Tags: java, jtextfield

Little background:
I have a JTextField called reading. It is located on a JFrame panel.

```
reading = new JTextField("waiting for entry");
```

What I am trying to do is amend the JTextField to where it creates a blinking effect. Appears, and then disappears. I want that to alert the user that it needs attention.

So is there a way where I at a blink of an eye, its sometimes a blank string, sometimes showing 'waiting for entry':

```
reading.setText("           ");

reading.setText("Waiting for entry");
```

Any suggestions?

In the same class I have :

```
    public void test(){
    int delay = 300; //milliseconds
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        reading.setVisible(!reading.isVisible()); } };
    Timer ok = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
    ok.start();
```

and let me show you my actionListener when reading gets the value:

```
public class MyChangeAction implements ChangeListener{
    public  void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce){
      int value_MAP = slider.getValue();
      String str = Integer.toString(value_MAP);
      reading.setVisible(true); // I just added this 
      reading.setText("     MAP "+ str+" mm Hg ");
}}
```

So where do I type ok.stop(); or ok.cancel();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and have

```
private class BlinkTask extends TimerTask
{
    public void run()
    {
        reading.setVisible(!reading.isVisible());
    }
}
```

registered to run every second or so.
Some Examples: [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/TimerScheduleataskthatexecutesonceeverysecond.htm)

Comment: Ok I have implemented a swing timer. 
It is working.
However, in the JFrame , I also have a slider. when the slider value is changed, the reading gets a number value. Basically I want the blinking to stop once the user has provided a number to the Jtext. Maybe I can be like "if (reading.StartsWith=="  ") {stop the blinking } else { continue}

Comment: Keep a handel on the object that is accessible throughout the class. In the ActionListener method that gives reading its value, have a `reading.setVisible(true);` and a `timerVar.cancel();` which will cancel the blinking and make sure the JTextField is in the visible state.

Comment: @Reese, I have edited my question, I have implemented reading.setVisible(true) but I am still having trouble implementing the time variable cancellation method.

Comment: @Faraz: You're going to want to keep the `Timer ok` declaration as a private variable for the class so that other methods can access it. Set it up in the constructor for instance. Then you can start it with `ok.start()` where you want to begin the blinking, and have an `ok.cancel()` call in your `stateChanged` method. This will stop the blinking when the slider is changed.

Comment: Yes, I need to make it accessible within the stateChanged method. When I first defined it : Timer ok = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer)
How do I tell it that its not limited within that method and can be used in the statechanged method as well?

Comment: @Faraz: To make a variable accessible throughout the class, declare the reference variable (i.e. `private Timer ok;`) in the class, then define it `ok = new Timer();` in some method. Once you've done that, the reference variable `ok` is available to any method or inner class within that class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just going through this exercise, I learned a lot. I really appreciate you helping me out.